# My login doesn't validate properly

Tags: php, mysql

First of all, sorry for my english.

I'm making a simple login where it returns true when validates correctly and false when it doesn't. But it's not working, allways return true, even when it shouldn't. Here is my code

<-----file usuariodao.php
`

```
include 'conexion.php';
include '../entidades/usuario.php';

class usuarioDao extends conexion{
    protected static $conexion;

    private static function prenderConexion(){
        self::$conexion = conexion::conectar();
    }

    private static function apagarConexion(){
        self::$conexion = NULL;
    }

    public static function login($usuario){

        $query = "SELECT id,nombre,mail,nombreusuario,privilegio,fecharegistro FROM usuarios_ WHERE nombreusuario = :nombreusuario AND contrasena = :contrasena";

        self::prenderConexion();

        $resultado = self::$conexion->prepare($query);

        $resultado->bindValue(":nombreusuario",$usuario->getNombreusuario());
        $resultado->bindValue(":contrasena",$usuario->getContrasena());

        $resultado->execute();

        if(count($resultado->rowcount())>0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

}
`

//<-----file usuariocontrolador.php

```
<?php

include '../datos/usuariodao.php';
class usuarioControlador{
    public static function login($nombreusuario,$contrasena){
        $obj_usuario = new usuario();
        $obj_usuario -> getNombreusuario($nombreusuario);
        $obj_usuario -> getContrasena($contrasena);

        return usuariodao::login($obj_usuario);
    }
}
```

//<-----file index.php ("msantillan","desa2712") are the correct values.

```
<?php
include '../controladores/usuarioControlador.php';

echo usuarioControlador::login("msanatillan", "desa2712");
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: you gotta to love when programmers mix thier native language with the english parts of a programming language.. on topic `if(count($resultado->rowcount())>0){` looks wierd function count would normally be used on array's ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php ) not on integers what `$resultado->rowcount()` returns.

Comment: @RaymondNijland - right on.  I'll explain, `rowCount()` returns an int `0` or more.  We'll assume it's `0` no match.  Now if we do `echo count(0);` it says `1` which is `true`.  [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de0f7cfa83dff21a8f21f1093e79acc756fe9804)  Therefor no mater the row count, the IF condition is successful.  That said it's incorrect to query the password for a match in the DB.